# Error : MAC keys must not be null Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing an issue with Android Studio , I always get the below error

```
Error:MAC keys must not be null
```

This error occurs whenever I clean a project and build or run the project. I tried many solutions like invalidate cache, Clearing the project gradle file, installing new studio but none of the solutions work..

Also the standalone SDK Manager throws the below error everytime[I am not using any proxy] :

```
Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: peer not authenticated
```

I also couldn't find any log file indicating the cause of this error.

Some Logs : Caused by:

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException: MAC keys must not be null
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: MAC keys must not be null
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsKeyMaterialGenerator.engineGenerateKey0(TlsKeyMaterialGenerator.java:274)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsKeyMaterialGenerator.engineGenerateKey(TlsKeyMaterialGenerator.java:88)
    ... 135 more
2016-10-28 19:10:22,140 [2028535]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - MAC keys must not be null 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: MAC keys must not be null
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
```

Comment: are you able to browse google.com from your pc chrome

Comment: Yes, I can open the above url also.

Comment: are you able to launch standalone sdk manager and get all data list available there

Comment: I'm able to launch, only the installed ones show up, rest of them don't.

Comment: may be your antivirus blocking android studio loop back connection or jvm is blocked for that , check firewall also

Comment: Both firewall and antivirus are turned off.
Few of the dependency libraries also fail to download

Comment: then you can download sdk manager from  https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: I don't want to download sdk. I just want to run my project.

Comment: You need the SDK to download the dependencies for your project, though

Comment: I have all the SDK dependencies to run my project, but the Gradle doesn't sync, It always shows MAC keys must not be null

Comment: Are you using windows and sdk located in c drive, if yes then move it to someother drive and restart android studio and sync gradle

Comment: Did that, it didn't work

Comment: Did you changed the sdk location in preferences of android studio too